# Unable to build a phonegap app for android on OSX

Tags: android, cordova, build

I'm getting an error when i try to build a Phonegap android app on mac os. I made sure to have all the versions of the buildtools installed but when I run the Phonegap build android I get the following error:

Error: Error code 1 for command: /Users/sebs/Projects/R/teamstatusapp/platforms/android/gradlew with args: cdvBuildDebug,-b,/Users/sebs/Projects/R/teamstatusapp/platforms/android/build.gradle,-Dorg.gradle.daemon=true,-Pandroid.useDeprecatedNdk=true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using any thirdparty phonegap plugins? Create a fresh project without installing any thirdparty plugin and check it is working fine or not.